# error build: failed to emit precompiled header

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios-build

My Project is in Flutter

- I am going to run it on iOS but its not building up and showing an error

When i am going to run my project i am getting this issue

error build: failed to emit precompiled header **'/Users/mamini10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gkudgltppknmjngsajzgibmxylai/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_1BJN23ZJ0P7X9-clang_33H6DOZ65FUBK.pch' for bridging header '/Users/mamini10/Documents/Project/ProjectName/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'**

/Users/mamini10/Documents/Project/ProjectName/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:10:9: error build: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

[image: ERROR Description]

- Newly created project is working properly.
- I Tried uninstall android studio, xCode and Simulators.
- Tried all some of the version of xCode.

My Current Flutter

[image: SDK VERSION]

I had tried with xCode version

- Xcode - 14.3.1
- Xcode - 14.3
- Xcode - 14.2
- Xcode - 14.0

Tried Simulator Version

- iPhone 14 Pro Max 16.0 and 15.0
- iPhone 13 Pro Max 16.0 and 15.0

Comment: I am facing a similar error in my iOS project.